# ARCore: how to detect insufficient lighting?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, augmented-reality, arcore

ARCore will not be able to detect surfaces if the lighting is insufficient.

Question : how to detect insufficient lighting in order to be able to inform the user ?

I could use a timer to display an alert after a few seconds but I will not know if the lack of surface detection is due to an insufficient lighting or another reason (no feature points, etc...)

So, how to check if the insufficient lighting is the probable reason of the non-detection of planes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure how you could go on about this since I only used ARCore in Unity, but maybe you could measure the brightness of the pixels of the screen. You could use the average to see if it is too dark or too bright. Also, you could use average deviation to determine if pretty much all of the screen is dark/bright (low deviation), and not just specific parts (higher deviation).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no API for this. We let the user do the calibration sequence (for us it's catching some objects so that the user has to move the phone around) and if we don't have a plane after X tries we show a dialog like telling the user that he/she should find a place with better lighting or a more structured floor.